# AWS SDK 2 assume role

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, java-14, aws-java-sdk-2.x

```
@Bean
public DynamoDbClient amazonDynamoDB() {
    final AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder().roleSessionName(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).roleArn("roleArn").build();
    final StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider  stsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider = StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.builder().refreshRequest(assumeRoleRequest).build();
    return DynamoDbClient.builder().credentialsProvider(stsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider).region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();
}
```

getting error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient]: Factory
> method 'amazonDynamoDB' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException: STS client must not be null.  at
> spring.beans@5.2.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> at
> spring.beans@5.2.7.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
> ... 58 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: STS client must not be null.

Comment: Looks like you're passing a NULL value in one of the fields. You should debug it by checking the values of whatever you are passing on the line that generated the error.

Comment: It worked actually it's bit confusing but finally figured it out .. we have to setup sts client in request. @John Rotenstein

Answer (score 14):

In assume role request need to set sts client & it worked

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DynamoDbClient amazonDynamoDB() {
    final AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder().roleSessionName(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).roleArn("roleArn").build();
    final StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder().region(Region.EU_WEST_1).build();
    final StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider  stsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider = StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.builder().stsClient(stsClient).refreshRequest(assumeRoleRequest).build();
    return DynamoDbClient.builder().credentialsProvider(stsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider).region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: This was a requirement of the v1 SDK, and I was hoping that it was no longer required in the v2 SDK because it's [not documented](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sts/auth/StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.Builder.html). +1 for doing the debugging.

Comment: but there is no `stsClient` method mentioned in the [documentatiion for StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.Builder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sts/auth/StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.Builder.html)