# Assuming role in AWS is causing a credentials error

Tags: amazon-web-services, sts, aws-credentials

I am trying to use Glue schema registry service in AWS with scala (or java should be useful also) and I tested two ways to assume a role but it results in an error:

```
"Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()])"
```

I don't want to use environment variables so I tried STS to assume a role with the following code:

```
val assumeRoleRequest                = AssumeRoleRequest.builder.roleSessionName(UUID.randomUUID.toString).roleArn("roleArn").build
val stsClient                        = StsClient.builder.region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1).build
val stsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider = StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider.builder.stsClient(stsClient).refreshRequest(assumeRoleRequest).build

val glueClient = GlueClient
  .builder()
  .region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1)
  .credentialsProvider(stsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider)
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62930761/17221117

The second way I used is using the following AWS code [official documentation](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/sts/src/main/java/com/example/sts/AssumeRole.java)

But it fails also... I don't understand if this generate a token that I should use or just executing this code should work.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You need credentials to assume an IAM role. How are you supplying credentials to your app?

Comment: Ahhh... ok, so I should add the credentials to GlueClient and then assume the role? In this moment I am assuming role before including credentials.

Comment: Typically, when using an AWS compute service, you supply/configure an IAM role and the compute executes with credentials associated with that IAM role (Glue example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-an-iam-role.html)).